# Multiprocessing function not stopping

Tags: python, recursion, parallel-processing, resources

I am a bioinformaticist trying to create a script that will monitor the hardware resource usage of my scripts. The scripts can take up to 15 hours so I need something that will take snapshots periodically while the script is running.

I decided to run the two functions in parallel with the monitoring function (`get_stats()`) on a recursive timer to get the snapshots as they come. The `in_command()` function takes a text file with the os commands used to call the script pipelines.

My problem is, that the `get_stats()` function doesn't stop once the other script has stopped. I have a switch (`process_switch`) that should flip once the other function has finished and stopped the `get_stats()` function. I am new to parallel processing.

```
import psutil
import platform
from datetime import datetime
import multiprocessing
import time
import os
from threading import Timer
import multiprocessing as mp


def get_size(bytes, suffix="B"):
    """
    Scale bytes to its proper format
    e.g:
        1253656 => '1.20MB'
        1253656678 => '1.17GB'
    """
    factor = 1024
    for unit in ["", "K", "M", "G", "T", "P"]:
        if bytes < factor:
            return f"{bytes:.2f}{unit}{suffix}"
        bytes /= factor


def get_stats():
    global df
    global process_switch
    global start_time
    df['time'].append(time.time() - start_time)

    # Get core information
    df['total_cores'].append(psutil.cpu_count(logical=True))
    df['physical_cores'].append(psutil.cpu_count(logical=False))
    cpufreq = psutil.cpu_freq()

    # cpu frequency in Mhz
    df['max_frequency'].append(cpufreq.max)
    df['min_frequency'].append(cpufreq.min)
    df['current_frequency'].append(cpufreq.current)
    cpu_core = {}
    for i, percentage in enumerate(psutil.cpu_percent(percpu=True, interval=1)):
        cpu_core[str(i)] = percentage
    df['cpu_core'].append(cpu_core)

    # get ram information
    svmem = psutil.virtual_memory()
    df['total_memory'].append(get_size(svmem.total))
    df['available_memory'].append(get_size(svmem.available))
    df['used_memory'].append(get_size(svmem.used))
    df['percent_memory'].append(svmem.percent)

    # swap memory if it exists
    swap = psutil.swap_memory()
    df['swap_total'].append(get_size(swap.total))
    df['swap_free'].append(get_size(swap.free))
    df['swap_used'].append(get_size(swap.used))
    df['swap_percentage'].append(swap.percent)
    print(df)

    #check to see if the other function has finished and stop this process
    if process_switch == 1:
        t = Timer(20, get_stats)
        t.start()
    else:
        t.stop()


def in_command(file):
    #takes in a text file and runs the command lines located within and runs them sequentially
    global process_switch
    f = open(file,'r')
    f_lines = f.readlines()
    for line in f_lines:
        print(line)
        os.system(line)
    f.close()
    #turn off monitoring software
    process_switch = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":

    df = {'time': [], 'total_cores': [], 'physical_cores': [], 'max_frequency': [],
          'min_frequency': [], 'current_frequency': [], 'cpu_core': [], 'total_memory': [],
          'available_memory': [], 'used_memory': [], 'percent_memory': [], 'swap_total': [],
          'swap_free': [], 'swap_used': [], 'swap_percentage': []}


    process_switch = 1

    start_time = time.time()


    p1 = mp.Process(target=get_stats, args = ())
    p2 = mp.Process(target=in_command, args=('text_command.txt',))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()

    print(df)
    print('finished')
```

Comment: Each process runs in its own memory space, so variables are only global to within each process, not between them.

Comment: I think you'd need to define your global variables outside of the functions. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: Thanks martineau, that hadn't even crossed my mind. I thought it was an error within my code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks martineau! I had no idea that global variables were not shared, it makes sense now that I stop to think about it logically. For other people who are having this issue I was able to solve it by using the multiprocessing.Manager() function to declare the global variable. There is a great post about the problem here https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2019/02/19/sharing-global-variables-in-python-using-multiprocessing/ . Thanks for the help!